# How do I get around "CD/DVD 'ubuntu 13.04_Raring ringtail_-Release amd 64 (20130424) is required", to install updates to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dvd

I am trying to load updates from Ubuntu for 12.04 and am getting the following message that blocks the up dating.

> CD/DVD 'Ubuntu 13.04 *Raring Ringtail* - Release amd64 (20130424)' is required
>
> Please insert the above CD/DVD into the drive '/media/cdrom/' to install software packages from it.

I am a total novice so please do not short cut how to fix problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution found I in a previous post answered by KK Patel.

You need to edit source file

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Please place comment # in beginning of line containing deb cdrom (with 13.04 in the line).

Save file and try again.

It worked for me.
I don't know what caused this issue.
If anyone knows I would like to hear

Hans